# Is there a single word for "accidental information leakage"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm not talking about computers and coding!

Imagine there are some necessary information for doing a certain operation and they leaked out so the operation must be cancelled now!

and Can I say "He leaks the information"? or "the information leaks"?

Comment: an "accidental information leakage" as you describe could be referred to as an **indiscretion**, so you could say that "he was **indiscrete**" with respect to the leaked information. However, depending upon context, other words might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say "he leaks the information" because that sounds a bit like he is going for a pee.  Also "the information leaks" implies that the information is an entity unto itself and decided to leak.

Alternatives include:

- The information was leaked
- There was a breach
- There was a breach in security
- Due to a security violation
- The enemy came by critical information
- Security was breached
- A process failure lead to ...
- An unauthorized disclosure
- An accidental information leak occured
- Unauthorized data access lead to ...
- He divulged their secrets
- He passed on classified information
- The details were exposed